# variadic param method wrapper ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, wrapper, variadic

I am creating a framework and stuck while making a wrapper for the class

**logger.h** which has below method

```
-(void) logError:(nonnull NSString *) info, ...;
```

I made a wrapper of *logger.h* file name **Mlogger.h**

The wrapper file **Mlogger.h** is having same prototype

```
-(void) logError:(nonnull NSString *) info, ...;
```

My **Mlogger.m** file implementation is as,

```
-(void) logError:(nonnull NSString *) info, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, info);
    [[Logger sharedManager] logError:info];
      //LogError(info,args); //also tried with macro
    va_end(args);
}
```

macro is define in *logger.h* :

```
#define LogError(format, ...) [[Logger sharedManager] logError:format , ##__VA_ARGS__ ];
```

I have imported wrapper class **Mlogger.h** and perform a call like,

```
[logger logDebug:@"Initialized successfully"];
[logger logDebug:@"URL: %@",@"www.google.com"];
```

The first line print perfectly but the second line prints 
 **URL : Logger: 0x604000226cc0..**

expected output is 
 **URL: www.google.com**

> Is my implementation is correct? and not then how can i pass value of
>   variadic parameters?